# MPDF trying to stretch table to fit remaining height

Tags: php, html, css, pdf, mpdf

I'm using MPDF to generate a PDF file from a HTML page containing a table. I want the table to stretch out to fit the remaining space on the page.

This is the table I'm using:

[image]

I want that the last item stretches out so that the remaining space is filled too ( as explained above ). I've tried reproducing this in normal HTML, but that did work.

I've tried using `last-child` to stretch the last element, as stated above, this worked without MPDF, but when using MPDF it doesn't stretch.

Does anyone know how to accomplish this using MPDF?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found out that it isn't possible to use the last-child to an element in mPDF, even height and width aren't allowed to use on tables.
You have to find out an other way to do this, like with div's!

Comment: A liitle late to the party, how did you achieve it with divs?